# Save Hibernate entity with parend child relationships fails with foreign key error

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting violated - parent key not found while trying to save Hibernate Entity

I have parent entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1246376778314918671L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "PARENT_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "parent_id")
    private long parentId;

    @Column(name = "display_name")
    @Size(min = 1, max = 128)
    @NotBlank   
    private String displayName;

    @JsonManagedReference("childAssignments")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<ChildAssignment> childAssignments = new HashSet<ChildAssignment>(0);

    //regular getters and setters here
}
```

and child entity looks like (in database it has foreign key on parent_id field from parents table):

```
Entity
@Table(name = "child_assignments")
public class ChildAssignment implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5949955576511639261L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "seq", sequenceName = "CHILD_ASSIGNMENT_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "child_assignment_id")
    private long childAssignmentId;

    @Column(name = "parent_id")  
    private long parentId;   // getting error because after creating new parent it has not been set

    @Column(name = "site_id")
    private long siteId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Parent parent;

    // regular getters and setters here

}
```

After parent object and childAssignments object have been created I am adding childAssignment to parent

```
ChildAssignment ca = new ChildAssignment();
ca.setSiteId(1);
// I do not set parent_id here since I do not know it and expecting Hibernate to figure it out

parent.getChildAssignments().add(childAssignment);
session.save(parent);
```

Expected result is to save new parent entry with ID and after use this id to save child but seems like hibernate does not know about parent_id at the time of saving, how should I build my association to make it work? or some annotations on parent_id field?

**UPDATED**

I tried to remove parent_id or set it to @Transient on childAssignment entity, and get new error cannot insert NULL into table, it's obvious that Hibernate is trying to insert parent_id but do not populate it,

setting parent on a child does not help either

```
ChildAssignment ca = new ChildAssignment();
   ca.setSiteId(1);
   ca.setParent(parent)

   parent.getChildAssignments().add(childAssignment);
   session.save(parent);
```

What I am missing?

**SOLVED**

I solved a problem changing my childAssignment entity

```
@Transient -- add transient (just to have it)
@Column(name = parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false) -- add insertable and updatable  both equals to false
private parentId; 


.....

 @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id") -- remove  insertable = false, updatable = false options
 private Parent parent;
```

Comment: Please check example in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961071/hibernate-cascade-save-parent-child-with-sequenced-fk

Comment: how it would look like with my child entity class?

Comment: I do not think I have right solution in provided example, I should not change any DB settings to accomplish it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
ca.setParent(parent);
```

as well.

If you specify a two sided relationship then you must assign both sides in Java code, just as you would if it was pure Java.

Secondly, your declaration of a 'parentId' column is redundant. Hibernate will create that for you automatically.

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could provide a little explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: no, it did not 
ca.setNotification(parent);
parent.getchildAssignments().add(ca);

Comment: the problem is child parent_id has not been set, how would it know how to set it?

Comment: It knows how to set it because you should call ca.setParent(parent). The ability to do this is part of the Hibernate/JPA raison d'être. You should almost never be concerned with key values, particularly assigning them to a property.